# Percentage reduction at breakpoints

Tags: calculus

I'm struggling to wrap my head around this problem I'm trying to solve.

n is a non-negative int, where
n<sub>max</sub> is the upper limit of n, and 
n<sub>current</sub> ,
is the current value of n.

---

`Condition:`

If n<sub>current</sub> is brought below 35% of n<sub>max</sub>, then any all  reductions in n<sub>current</sub> will be decreased by 65% of the original reduction amount.

---

As such, if n<sub>current</sub> is reduced by n<sub>max</sub> + 1, then n<sub>current</sub> remains greater than zero.

For n<sub>max</sub> = 100, the initial reduction from 100 to 35 will be 1-to-1, while the remaining portion will be 1-to-0.65.

---

How can I express the "functional" value of n<sub>max</sub> and n<sub>current</sub>, as the expression of the real value of how much n<sub>current</sub> can be reduced by, before hitting 0?

Does my question make sense?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should clarify what are $n_{current}$ and $n_{max}$. One seems like a function of time but can it take only non negative integer values?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur thanks for reading :)
n is a number, where n_max is its upper limit, and n_current is its current value. It can be any non-negative integer. I'm trying to figure out what the function should be, that allows the behaviour I outlined under the condition, where making n_current less than 35% of n_max diminishes the value subtraction :)

Comment: Do you want to say that $n$ is a function from $[0,\infty)$ to $\{  0,1,2,3..... \}$, Or is $n$ a sequence of numbers? Your notations are confusing to me,  and it would perhaps be beneficial to write the value of $n$ at $t$ as $n(t)$. Furthermore I assume that you want to say that $n_{max}\geq n(t)$ for all $t$, which is called an upper bound and not an upper limit necessarily.

Comment: I'm not big on math, so it's hard to express with the proper terms :D   
f(i)=n. n is the output of a function. Where the output is a positive int. n_max is the upper bound of that function's return value.